# I want to make a type bot which will join my classes automatically i have tried it but got the error

Tags: python, schedule

### I want to make a type bot  which will join my classes automatically i have tried it but got the error

#### Importing All the modules Needed

```
import schedule
import webbrowser
import pyttsx3
import timetable
import time
```

#### Join Class Function for joining classes

```
def joinclass(classname):
    zoomlinks=timetable.zoomlinks
    webbrowser.open(zoomlinks[classname])
    pyttsx3.speak(f"joining {classname}")
```

#### Monday's code for joining classes

```
schedule.every().monday.at("08:30").do(joinclass("Assembly"))
schedule.every().monday.at("08:40").do(joinclass("Hindi"))
schedule.every().monday.at("09:30").do(joinclass("Elit"))
schedule.every().monday.at("10:05").do(joinclass("Maths"))
schedule.every().monday.at("11:15").do(joinclass("History"))
schedule.every().monday.at("12:05").do(joinclass("PT"))
```

#### Tuesday's code for joining classes

```
schedule.every().tuesday.at("08:30").do(joinclass("Assembly"))
schedule.every().tuesday.at("08:40").do(joinclass("Maths"))
schedule.every().tuesday.at("09:30").do(joinclass("Geography"))
schedule.every().tuesday.at("10:05").do(joinclass("Biology"))
schedule.every().tuesday.at("11:15").do(joinclass("Physics"))
schedule.every().tuesday.at("12:05").do(joinclass("Gk"))
```

#### Wednesday's code for joining classes

```
schedule.every().wednesday.at("08:30").do(joinclass("Assembly"))
schedule.every().wednesday.at("08:40").do(joinclass("Hindi"))
schedule.every().wednesday.at("09:30").do(joinclass("Elit"))
schedule.every().wednesday.at("10:05").do(joinclass("Telugu"))
schedule.every().wednesday.at("11:15").do(joinclass("Chemistry"))
schedule.every().wednesday.at("12:05").do(joinclass("Elang"))
```

#### Thursday's code for joining classes

```
schedule.every().thursday.at("08:30").do(joinclass("Assembly"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("08:40").do(joinclass("Geography"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("09:30").do(joinclass("Maths"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("10:05").do(joinclass("Telugu"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("11:15").do(joinclass("Chemistry"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("12:05").do(joinclass("Elang"))
```

#### Friday's code for joining classes

```
schedule.every().thursday.at("08:30").do(joinclass("Assembly"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("08:40").do(joinclass("Elang"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("09:30").do(joinclass("Maths"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("10:05").do(joinclass("Computer"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("11:15").do(joinclass("History"))
schedule.every().thursday.at("12:05").do(joinclass("Biology"))
```

#### To Run join the pending classes

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### I got an Error like this:-

> self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
> TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're calling the functions like this:

```py
schedule.every().monday.at("08:30").do(joinclass("Assembly"))
#                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

when you should call them like this:

```py
schedule.every().monday.at("08:30").do(joinclass, "Assembly")
#                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Off-topic, but you can simplify your code using dictionaries:

```
frame = {
    'monday': {
        '08:30': 'Assembly',
        '08:40': 'Hindi',
        '09:30': 'Elit',
        '10:05': 'Maths',
        '11:15': 'History',
        '12:05': 'PT',
    },
    'tuesday': {
        '08:30': 'Assembly',
        '08:40': 'Maths',
        '09:30': 'Geography',
        '10:05': 'Biology',
        '11:15': 'Physics',
        '12:05': 'Gk',
    },
    # Do the same for all the weekdays
}
```

Then, using the above dictionary (`frame`), you can run all schedules using this code:

```
for weekday, frame_schedule in frame.items():
    for time, subject in frame_schedule.items():
        getattr(schedule.every(), weekday).at(time).do(joinclass, subject)
```

Comment: Thank you That Works but can you please explain the the dicts and the of topic part